# I keep getting the error "Index exceeds array bounds"

Tags: matlab, optimization, neural-network, nonlinear-optimization, particle-swarm

> there are some issues, my input is 30*27 and output is 1*30 but this
>   code is making some issue.    keep getting the error Index exceeds array bounds from the matlab own code file, input matrix is 27x30 double

```
 % INITIALIZE THE NEURAL NETWORK PROBLEM %
    % inputs for the neural net(AND gate example== 2 inputs && 4 samples)
    inputs = inputs';
    % targets for the neural net
    targets = TargetNormalized';
    % number of neurons
    n = 4;
    % create a neural network
    net = feedforwardnet(n);
    % configure the neural network for this dataset
    net = configure(net, inputs, targets);
    % get the normal NN weights and bias
    getwb(net)
    % error MSE normal NN
    error = targets - net(inputs);
    calc = mean(error.^2)/mean(var(targets',1))
    % create handle to the MSE_TEST function, that
    % calculates MSE
    h = @(x) NMSE(x, net, inputs, targets);
    % Setting the Genetic Algorithms tolerance for
    % minimum change in fitness function before
    % terminating algorithm to 1e-8 and displaying
    % each iteration's results.
    % PLEASE NOTE: For a feed-forward network
    % with n hidden neurons, 3n+n+1 quantities are required
    % in the weights and biases column vector.
    % a. n for the input weights=(features*n)=2*n
    % b. n for the input biases=(n bias)=n
    % c. n for the output weights=(n weights)=n
    % d. 1 for the output bias=(1 bias)=1
    % running the particle swarm optimization algorithm with desired options
    [x, err_ga] = pso(h, 2*n+n+n+1)
    net = setwb(net, x');
    % get the PSO optimized NN weights and bias
    getwb(net)
    % error MSE PSO optimized NN
    error = targets - net(inputs);
    calc = mean(error.^2)/mean(var(targets',1))
```

i am keep getting this error.

```
% Index exceeds array bounds.
Error in separatewb (line 34)
    iw{i,j} = reshape(wb(hints.iwInd{i,j}),...
Error in setwb (line 23)
[b,IW,LW] = separatewb(net,wb,hints);
Error in NMSE (line 7)
 net = setwb(net, wb);
Error in main>@(x)NMSE(x,net,inputs,targets)
Error in pso (line 67)
    particle(i).Cost=CostFunction(particle(i).Position);
Error in main (line 43)
[x, err_ga] = pso(h, 2*n+n+n+1)


'''
```

please help

1. coding
   sampling

Comment: You should have included the `matlab` tag (added).

Comment: i have added, could you please help me with the answer

Comment: yes, i still cannot find the answer